# Select single item from database with Spring Hibernate Sessionfactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, sessionfactory

This is in my DAO:

```
public List<Weather> getCurrentWeather() {  
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Weather").list();
}
```

This gets all of the elements from table Weather. But lets say I wanna do something like this(I want only one element from table Weather):

```
public Weather getCurrentWeather() {    
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Weather where id = 1").list(); // here should be something else than list()
}
```

**I know there should not be** `list()` **in the end, but what must I write there, to get only one object?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have an id, you just use get:

```
public Weather getCurrentWeather() {    
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Weather.class, 1); 
}
```

If you do need to do a query, yeah you'll have to grab the top of the result set, or you can use `uniqueResult()` on the query.

Comment: UniqueResult() is an object, how would you handle the difference of Weather and normal object? Should I just maniacally cast it to Weather? Or there is a more suitable way?

Comment: Yes, you cast it.  There is no such thing as compile time type safety with queries.  How is the compiler supposed to know what your HQL statement is going to create in the end?

Comment: But does this work when I have something else than ID, for example some integer field?

Comment: get is only for ids.  It is advisable to use it as much as possible, since it goes to the L1 cache.  That may be irrelevant if you have tight request scopes and are sure to only get it once per session anyway.  If you want to avoid the casting you could use the Criteria API to build your query instead of writing out HQL.

Comment: Casting is required with the first option also? Doesn't the `(Weather.class, 1)` thing return Weather class?

Comment: When I use UniqueResult(), and actually the query returns more than one result, what would happen? Will it give error or just return the first one?

Comment: It will throw an exception if the result is not unique http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html

Answer (score 11):

Is there something wrong with getting a list? :)  Even if you know there is only 1 hibernate cannot assume that.  Getting a list is safer anyway!

```
public Weather getCurrentWeather() {    
    List<Weather> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Weather where id = 1").list(); // here should be something else than list()
    return (list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0));
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about getting list, but I thought whether there is another way also. Nevertheless, should I handle the change from List to Weather in DAO as you did, or just handle it in my view, by getting the first element of the list there? Which would be the proper use?

Comment: Well it's really up to you, but unless you want lists being returned to your view all the time, I would do it in the DAO level.  Also, the method name suggests you just want the current weather so other people later using your code may be confused as to why a list is being returned

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Criteria API as below:

```
    List<LeaveManagement> leaveManagements =      session.createCriteria(LeaveManagement.class)
            .add( Restrictions.isNull("approvedTimeStamp") )
            .uniqueResult();

    If you want to write a hql query you can write as:

    String hql = "from LeaveManagement where approvedTimeStamp is null";
         Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        LeaveManagement results = (LeaveManagement) query.uniqueResult();
```